# C struct: consecutive fields without padding?

Tags: c, struct, padding

`any_t` is any type (`int`, `struct something`, …).

Consider this structure:

```
struct my_struct {
    any_t val,
    any_t array[10]
}
```

If I define a variable `v`:

```
struct my_struct v;
```

Is it safe to use `&v.val` as an array of 11 `any_t` items?

```
any_t *p = &v.val;
f(p[0]);
f(p[5]);
f(p[10]);
```

Is it guaranteed no padding will be added between `val` and `array`?

Comment: You could use #pragma pack(1) to guarantee no spacing between members

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member worth reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the C standard alone, it is not safe to use `&v.val` as an array of 11 `any_t` for these reasons:

- The C standard permits unnamed internal padding in a struct: C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.2.1 15, “There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.” It would be unusual for a C implementation to insert padding between `val` and `array`, because alignment requirements would not require it, but it is permitted and it is conceivably beneficial in certain circumstances, such as causing `array` to be better aligned for performance (rather than necessity).
- Even if there were a guarantee that the spacing of `val` and the `array` elements were the same as an array of 11 `any_t`, there is no guarantee that pointer arithmetic works. C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.6 8 defines pointer arithmetic (including array indexing), and it only requires that arithmetic work **within an array** (including one notional element at the end). Some C implementations use base-and-offset addressing. In such cases, a base address for `val` might fail to support offsets that extend into `array`.
- Even if a C implementation uses simple flat addressing, its optimizer is permitted to make deductions based on the C standard. The optimizer can, in theory, see that a pointer is derived from the address of `val` and therefore cannot (in accordance with the C standard) be used to address anything in `array`. E.g., if you did `any_t *p = &v.val; p[i] = 3; v.array[j] = 4;`, the optimizer may treat the assignments to `v.array[j]` and `p[i]` as independent and perform them in any order, even though you may have set `i` and `j` so that they would point to the same element.

Comment: The standard seems a little bit murky with regard to what an implementation could or could not legitimately do with regard to pointers that extend beyond the declared size of an array; as yet I'm unaware of anything that either justifies or deprecates the "traditional" version of the "struct hack" (using a size-one array).  With regard to your latter points, however, I would think that if a struct were within malloc'ed space, casting an address of an element to a `void*` and then back to its element type should guarantee that things should work if things are in fact located in the right place.

Comment: Unless the particular implementation is specified, I don't think there's any portable way to use array-ish accessing for structure members unless one has defines an array of offsets to expressly-listed struct members (among other things, there's no guarantee that members will be equally spaced), but I think that if a struct is within malloc'ed space, it's guaranteed to have its members overlap the appropriate bytes therein.

Comment: It is incorrect to use a model about address space to reason about C semantics (e.g., given that members will be at certain byte offsets, therefore they form an array) because the C standard does not define such a model. To reason properly, you must deduce behavior from the statements in the standard. As I noted, the optimizer can do unexpected things. Even if you allocate space with `malloc`, set `v` to point to it, and all the elements are at the expected offsets, if you set `any_t *p = &v->val`, then the optimizer is permitted to behave as if `p[i]` is not `v->array[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing is guaranteed by the standard. Your specific compiler implementation may certainly make guarantees beyond those made by the standard, though.  Check your documentation for all the details.

Comment: Alignment requirements are not relevant. The `val` and `array` members would have the same alignment requirements, so padding for `val` caused by alignment requirements would be the same as padding for `array` elements caused by alignment requirements. The standard permits unnamed padding between `val` and `array`, but an implementation would not be inserting padding for alignment requirements. (Hypothetically, it might insert padding for alignment benefits, e.g., if it would help align `array` to a cache line, and the compiler has reason to believe that would be beneficial.)

Comment: Fair enough; second sentence removed.

Answer (score 0):

Well your definition of the struct is about 2 fields, so your compailer may not use it as an arry of 11 elements, so you will have to fill your fileds as they are decleared.